# Can I combine RAW & JPEG after import in Aperture?

Tags: raw, jpeg, apple-aperture, iphoto

I'm trying out Aperture; I have a hefty collection of photos in iPhoto, and for a few reasons, it's not cutting it for me anymore.

I recently started shooting RAW+JPEG on my camera. I see that Aperture copes with this quite well, and imports both images allowing me to choose one as the master file. iPhoto has no notion of this, and since I have imported many photos into iPhoto already, I have many duplicates in Aperture, with one being the RAW and one the JPEG.

I would like to combine these individual RAW & JPEG photos in Aperture just as if I had imported them from the camera as RAW+JPEG, with the RAW as the master.

Is such a thing possible? Is it even a good idea, or should I just trash any JPEG for which I have a RAW master in Aperture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You nailed it in your last question.

The RAW file contains more information that the JPG does.  This means that Aperture is (non-destructively!) going to be able to create better images, have multiple variations, and do so all non-destructively.

If you need JPG files, have Aperture generate them for you with any size or quality you desire.

If you have the RAW, there is no need to keep the JPGs around.

So, why do cameras offer both?  Simple.  Some applications can't read RAW files and the JPG is a fall back.

Comment: Misleading answer. One reason one may want to keep the JPEGs generated in-camera, in addition to RAW files, is because the on-board JPEG algorithm in many cameras generates images with a particular character that cannot simply be replicated by clicking "Convert to JPEG" in your library software. For example, the Fujifilm X-Series has several proprietary "Film simulation" modes that generate JPEGs which mimic classic Fuji film stock and other aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to automatically combine them in stacks, using the "Auto-stack" feature.

You can find it in Stacks > Auto-Stack or by pressing Command - Option - A.

Then you can select the time-difference in seconds between the photos, that need in order to be contained in the same stack.

Having in mind that these were taken at the same time, then probably using the default 0:00 option will be ok with you, but you may also try increase it by 1 sec.

I hope this helps! :)

George

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to add the RAWs to your already imported JPEGs, although I only tried it for JPEGs which were imported by Aperture (though without their corresponding RAWs) and not JPEGs which were migrated from iPhoto.

Procudure I used:

- Organize the RAWs so they match your project structure (I already had a raw-subdirectory for each project)
- Click the import toolbar item (or Shift-Cmd-i IIRC)
- On the right select "Import RAW only", then below that you can select import only matching, select that too
- Select the directory with the RAWs
- Click on the project containing the JPEGs

This did the trick for me!

HTH, Greetings
-Sascha-