# What combination of R, G, B lasers will give "White" with a given °K temperature?

Tags: lighting, laser, rgb, color-white

Would it be possible to get a "white" lighting of a subject by using 3 different lasers (R, G and B)

If so, which wavelengths and proportions should be used ?

Comment: Why use lasers? Mixing R G and B LEDs can look fairly good. LEDs have a much wider spectrum than a laser. Though the calibration will be tricky since as @Michael Nielsen said, humans and cameras will see the mix differently.

Comment: To light the subjects with coherent, monochromatic light.

Comment: Are you making a color hologram?

Comment: @Phil: I confess I am not.

Comment: It would be nice if I knew more about what you want to achieve. Here is a short answer assuming for some reason you need monochromatic, coherent light to take a photo using a common digital camera. If this is the case, don't worry about the color balance. You will likely need all the photons your lasers can make. Take a picture with a white subject and set the ratio of each channel later.

Comment: @Phil : Excellent idea... Many thanks. You'll be kept updated about the results if you wish.

Comment: Your problem has an infinite number of solutions. Basically, almost any R, G and B wavelengths can be combined to make almost any white. The problem is is that, although your white source will have the intended color, it will also have a catastrophic [color rendering index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_rendering_index)

Comment: @EdgarBonet: thank you so much for the reference to the Color Rendering Index....

Comment: @EdgarBonet: question : how would that catastrophic color rendering index exactly translate in a portrait photography for example ? Would the color of the skin appear to be unnatural, if a picture is taken ?

Comment: Yes, you can expect an unnatural skin color, although the actual rendering can only be calculated if you know the reflectance spectrum of the skin.

Answer (score 4):

You can get white LED lights that like monitors do actually create white from combinations of very narrow bands of R, G and B light - we perceive it as white of a certain "Kelvin" balance, but if you use a spectrometer, you will see spikes.

http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~schubert/Light-Emitting-Diodes-dot-org/chap20/chap20.htm

The same goes for fluorescent lights:

http://web.ncf.ca/jim/misc/cfl/

Compared to old light bulbs and halogen the benefit is that they don't emit IR light, ie. waste so much power on heat, which is why we see them as brighter at lower watts. However, cameras will see them as really dim, because the integration of the sensor's sensitivity curve times the emitting source curve ends up rather small, with all those spikes.

Answer (score 3):

No. "White" light contains all wavelengths of light - the Kelvin temperature just affects the proportions of each wavelength. Three lasers will have just three specific wavelengths so can't possibly reproduce the full spectrum of light that is in white light.

Comment: Could you please expand a little bit more ? How would a person lit with equal proportions of R, G and B lasers look different from it she were lit with a white light ? Would the CCD sensor of a camera be able to "feel" the difference ? If that is not possible, then how are monitors able to display color images from only red, green and white pixels ?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10385/best-fluorescent-bulb-color-temperature-for-shooting-people-and-interviews

Comment: What if your lasers very closely matched the primaries used by the R, G, B filters in your camera?

Comment: @mattdm: how may I know about those filter's frequencies ?

Comment: @Skippy: Good question! I imagine it varies slightly from sensor model to sensor model.

Comment: @mattdm: well, I would expect the Red (resp. G, B) filters to be sensitive to all Red (resp. G, B) wavelengths ! Or there would be black spots on the pictures, correponding to areas lit by the "blind" wavelengths! (a kind of Spectral Macula ! OMG that's scary)

Comment: @Skippy: I expect there's even some overlap. I don't know how much or what the peaks are, though. Fundamentally, they are the primaries in the camera's native color space.