# What software raw converter can convert from .raf to .jpg, replicating the Fujifilm in-camera raw conversion algorithm?

Tags: raw, workflow, jpeg, fujifilm, adobe-camera-raw

#### Why I ask for software

To perform batch conversion of many existing .raf files to .jpg.

#### Why I want Fujifilm's algorithm, specifically

I have tried Lightroom and Silkypix, and both fail to give usable results when converting from RAF to JPG. The results are shockingly hideous (as in, one would not expect this sort of thing from them), with blown out blue and extreme loss of detail, not to mention that it's completely inaccurate color representation. Silkypix is not as bad as Adobe in that it has more detail, but its color representation is also off.

Here is an example. It's a white, lace curtain lit by light blue stage lighting.

Left: Lightroom with ACR 7.5, Right: Fujifilm X100 converted in-camera
[image: Example: white curtain lit by blue stage lighting. Left: Lightroom with ACR 7.5, Right: Fujifilm X100 converted in-camera]

Comment: Can you tell us what OS you're using?  As there are OS integrated raw format viewers which might be useful in this situation.

Comment: I was using Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 2):

Typically the only way to replicate the same RAW conversion as a manufacturer uses in camera is to use the software that they provide(typically with the camera). In this case I think you want to first try [MyFinePix Studio](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/myfinepix_studio/). I don't have the software, and the website is pretty vague on if it includes RAW conversion or not, they make it sound like strictly a "viewer". But I did find "MyFindPix Studio RAW FILE CONVERTER" that Fuji has on their website for some specific camera models [here](http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/software/myfinepix_studio/rfc/v3220/index.html). So you may have to search the Fuji support site for your specific camera model, but it looks like at least for some cameras they provide this exact software you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the research and the links. I did try MyFinePix Studio, and was able to confirm that it is just a viewer, rather than a developer. 

Not intuitively, the "MyFinePix Studio RAW FILE CONVERTER" happens to be the same thing as the Silkypix software, if I'm not mistaken. While it comes from Fujifilm and has the X100 on there, surprisingly, it doesn't convert the same way as from in-camera. I suppose this is something I'll have to just take up with Fujifilm.

Answer (score 1):

I used X100 and today I shooting with X-E1 and facing same issue (especially for X-E1, it has unsupported sensor).

No software at the moment can convert RAW files exactly same with default settings as in-camera Fuji process. I would suspect that Silkypix will be closest, but it is still miles away from beautiful X-E1 JPEGs.

For X100 I used workaround of shooting JPEG + RAW and then edit RAW in Lightroom to look similar to JPEG and results were outstanding. With RAW I could usually get much better results when finished. Unfortunately, this is not the case with my new X-E1 - image details are ruined, not recoverable :/

One more tip for X100: Capture One 7 has best default settings for X100 I have seen.