# How can I set my Canon 5D Mark II to JPEG only?

Tags: jpeg, camera-settings, canon-5d-mark-ii

I'm trying to find out how to set JPEG only mode on my Canon 5D Mark II - which options do I need to set from which menus?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean a 5D MK II (spelt with a capital i not a 1), Menu -> "first tab" (in red) -> Quality -> shutter wheel to set RAW to "none" and aperture wheel to set JEPG.
(Must have on button in the correct place, might work with the joystick too.)

BUT I would HIGHLY recommend to always shoot RAW.
Some groups apparently need the fast JPEG (e.g. photojournalists at sports events) but even in that case I would suggest you obtain a RAW file which you can edit later on.

Comment: RAW + JPEG is the way forward.

Comment: FYI - I've just edited the question so it unambiguously refers to the 5D II.

Comment: @MattGrum That's a matter of opinion (says "Mr RAW only" :)

Comment: I voted this down because I disagree "always shoot RAW", not because the steps you provided to change the quality setting are incorrect.

Comment: @dpolitt name a single case where not having the RAW is a benefit. Correct, there is none. There is a special case where you may need an immediate JPEG - e.g. the aforementioned photojournalist, but then you can shoot JPEG + RAW.

Comment: @DetlevCM When you have limited storage for whatever reason not having the RAW means you can store many more JPEG frames. I did this this summer on a trip after picking up a Sony A7R, I have a huge number of CF cards but very few SD cards (I wanted to evaluate the camera before investing in cards). I shot RAW only rather than RAW + JPEG to save space. Most of the time I shoot RAW + JPEG for convenience as storage is usually not a problem.

Comment: We've got a good Q&A on the "why RAW+JPG" question [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/why-store-both-jpeg-and-raw).

Comment: @matt I personally shoot RAW only - I can create JPEGs at home. Space may be an issue - but this is possibly more of a planning issue. I recently got the G7 X for a holiday - my 5D MK II takes CF cards. -> I bought one 64GB SD card for the G7 X for 30 pounds and that sorted that. (Ironically that means I have more space on 1 SD card than on CF cards....) - Buying a card that is large enough for at least 1 day isn't hard - nor are they that expensive any more in relative terms.

Comment: That's fine. I just wanted to redirect to the in-depth Q&A rather than having an argument in the comments. :)