# What's the difference between Raw Vs Raw+L mode?

Tags: raw, digital, jpeg

Whats the difference between raw mode and raw+L mode on a digital camera? Which is best for commercial photography?

Comment: See also [Why store both JPEG and raw?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/why-store-both-jpeg-and-raw)

Comment: Honestly, if you have to ask what the difference is between raw and raw+L you're probably not ready to do commercial photography, at least digitally, anytime soon.

Comment: Why didn't you read your camera manual?

Answer (score 6):

"RAW mode" produces only a RAW file for each picture; "RAW + L" mode produces two files for each picture: both a RAW file and a (full-size) JPEG.

As for which is best, that's a decision you have to make based on your own circumstances - are the advantages of having both formats more important than the disadvantages (smaller bursts, more space taken up on memory cards)?